# Keep connection when switching scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to keep my connection between the server and my clients, when the clients are switching the scene. How it could be possible?

Comment: Don't you just get tired of that edit @steven? ;)

Comment: What exactly are you currently using for your server connections @Coucka? There are several ways to have objects persist between scenes. So it would be good to see what you're currently doing.

Comment: @Bart: I do actually, but I'm too stubborn to stop :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection is tied to a MonoBehaviour you can just call **DontDestroyOnLoad** on that object.

Something like this

```
DontDestroyOnLoad( connectionObject );
```

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

Note: you need to destroy the object by hand by calling **Destroy** when don't need it any more.

If the connection is not tied to a MonoBehaviour you need to keep a reference to it from an object that is not destroyed, for instance a Singleton.